# How do I repaint a winForm

Tags: vb.net

I have a winForm that upon Load it runs some code from a module. I want my form to remain on top while the code runs, the form contains a progress bar so it's imperative that the user sees the progress.

I have set up my form to `TopMost=True` and `ShowDialog`

The problem I have is that while the procedures are performing their work, the form is not visible. On my old VBA days I used `Repaint` to fix this problem, but I do not have such option with VB.net. I have done some research and I various places I saw using `Invalidate`, but nothing there either.

How can I prevent my form from disappearing and make sure that it remains on top while the code runs.

```
 Private Sub frmDataImportSplash_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim intProgressWidth As Integer = 214
        Dim intProgress As Integer = 0

        'Before procedures perform the following checks:
        'Check to see if Cancel has been clicked

        'Set the lblProgressBar width to 0
        'Change the lblPctCompleted caption to 0% Completed
        'Change the lblStatus Caption to Importing Files
        'Display the lblStats

        checkCancel(Cancel:=False)

        Me.prgStatus.Width = 0
        Me.lblPctCompleted.Text = "0% Completed"
        Me.lblStatus.Text = "Preparing Imports"
        Me.lblStatus.Visible = True


        checkCancel(Cancel:=False)
        Me.Invalidate()
        Me.prgStatus.Width = 20
        intProgress = (Me.prgStatus.Width / intProgressWidth) * 100
        Me.lblPctCompleted.Text = intProgress & "% Completed"
        Me.Invalidate()

'Here is where my form dissapears
        formatModule.importSheets()

        checkCancel(Cancel:=False)
        Me.Invalidate()
        Me.prgStatus.Width = 60
        intProgress = (Me.prgStatus.Width / intProgressWidth) * 100
        Me.lblPctCompleted.Text = intProgress & "% Completed"
        Me.Invalidate()
        formatModule.prepareExports()

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: The fact that the form does not display during processing clearly indicates that the code should really be in running a background thread.  Take a look at the BackgroundWorker() control...

Comment: @Idle_Mind this is great information. I am new to programming so I had not heard of this control. Upon reading on it, I think this will be perfect for what I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your doing this in the Form_Load event - which occurs before the form is shown. You can move this code to the form_shown event. Then the code will run after the form is shown to the user.

Comment: Excellent, that was all that I needed to do. Thanks.